# Essa pergunta está no escopo do site?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Já vi várias questões referentes a AWS no SOpt então não vi problemas em postar minha dúvida, esta que na verdade que é bem de novato porque não estou conseguindo configurar o básico.

A minha pergunta foi votada como **fora do escopo** do site apesar de eu achar que se encaixa em "ferramentas comuns entre programadores" e existir as tags referentes a minha dúvida. 
Minha dúvida é: Está fora do escopo por abordar sobre AWS ou há algum problema específico na minha pergunta?

[Configurar domínio na Amazon com Route 53](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78526/configurar-dom%C3%ADnio-na-amazon-com-route-53)

Comment: Também fiquei na dúvida ao ver a pergunta, mas parece-me ser dentro do escopo.

Comment: Fiquei na dúvida especificamente por existir uma questão que aborda o mesmo assunto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23050/como-ligar-um-dom%C3%ADnio-j%C3%A1-comprado-a-um-site-na-amazon-ec2
Seria útil quando votar negativo ou sinalizar uma questão logo em seguida fazer comentários com sugestões

Comment: Daniela tens toda a razão era mesmo útil se toda a gente fizesse isso, pelo menos o primeiro a votar ou sinalizar.

Comment: Me parece perfeitamente válida também...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Acredito que tenham votado como **fora do escopo** pela maneira como ela foi redigida. Veja:

- Não há nenhum ponto específico na questão que pode ser abordado para tentar solucionar o problema. Não há código, não há configuração realizada, somente um link para um tutorial, que a gente supõe estar correto. E a gente também supõe que você o seguiu corretamente (não temos como saber!)
- A questão parece ser voltada para configuração de serviço de hospedagem e não sobre as APIs ou comandos do `aws`, que eu acredito serem mais condizentes com "ferramentas comuns entre programadores".
- No meio da questão, você diz que o serviço funcionava de forma intermitente, indicando a possibilidade da sua configuração estar correta.

O que eu acho que aconteceu, foi que algumas pessoas não entenderam como poderiam te ajudar, não acharam **possível** te ajudar, e votaram para fechar, baseado na compreensão que tiveram da questão (fora de escopo).

Eu, na primeira vez que li, votaria como fora de escopo também. Agora não acho exatamente que esteja, mas votaria para fechar de qualquer maneira, como **ampla demais**.

Eu acredito que sua questão, na melhor das hipóteses, esteja soando assim: *"Eu estou fazendo um programa em java, segui esse [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html). Na primeira vez ele compilou, mas não funcionou. Agora nem compila. O que eu posso estar fazendo de errado?"* - Uma questão que não está fora do escopo, mas não tem como permanecer aberta.

Aliás, eu não acharia estranho se sua questão fosse fechada também no [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/708550/googledomains-with-aws).

Comment: Concordo Daniel, a pergunta é ampla demais e faltam informações para ter uma resposta adequada

Comment: Muito bem respondido.